RF Heating in a Dielectric
Trying to understand RF heating in dielectrics. Suppose I have a high frequency AC current around 50 - 100 MHz on a wire adjacent to a dielectric. This creates an associated electric field.
In the dielectric there is a displacement field, \$\textbf{D}\$:
\begin{equation}
\textbf{D} = \varepsilon_{0} \textbf{E} + \textbf{P}
\end{equation}
where \$\varepsilon_{0}\$ is the permeability of free space and \$\textbf{P}\$ is the polarization. There is an associated displacement current density \$\textbf{J}\$:
\begin{equation}
\textbf{J}=\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t} = \varepsilon_{0} \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
then by Joule's Law there should be a power density \$\textbf{P}\$:
\begin{equation}
\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{J}=\textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t} = \varepsilon_{0}\textbf{E}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
So now my question is, if this is correct, what is the physical interpretation of \$\partial\textbf{D} / \partial t\$, \$\partial\textbf{E}/\partial t\$, and
\$\partial\textbf{P}/\partial t\$? I presume that the \$\partial\textbf{P}/\partial t\$ represents the flipping of molecular dipoles such as water to create friction. Does the \$\partial\textbf{E}/\partial t\$ term give rise to currents from free charges to the extent they are present in the dielectric? Thanks.

A very similar question was already posted on physics SE.

@ThePhoton and by the same author :)

For a good dielectric epsilon is a real number. The displacement current is then 90 degrees out of phase with the electric field. The average power provided by the field is zero. In the language of power electronics, there is reactive power but no real power supplied. There is no heat but there is stored energy.
A lossy dielectric can often be modeled with epsilon having a nonzero imaginary part. In that case there would be nonzero heating.

That works if we are doing phasor representations, but OP has presented the question in the time domain. Then $Im{\hat\varepsilon} = j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$ where $\hat\varepsilon$ is the complex permittivity and $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the material.

Sorry, I couldn't get that equation to work. I mean we have to deal with polarizability and conductivity separately, rather than lump them into a complex permittivity.

Is $$\Im\left{\hat\varepsilon\right} = j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$$ better? (you forgot a backslash before the closing curly bracket)
